# Combobox in telerik radgridview for winforms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox, telerik

I'm trying to embed a combobox in telerik gridview, but it's not even loading in the grid.

I'm trying to get the values from the table in database by using a stored procedure.

My version of code is below:

```
Private Sub GetDocType()
    Try
        Dim db As New gpcdb.dbaccess
        Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
        cmd = db.GetSqlDBCmd("gpc_DocumentType", CommandType.StoredProcedure)
        Dim ddlDocType As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn = New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn

        cmd.Connection.Open()

        ddlDocType.ValueMember = "gpcDocTypeID"
        ddlDocType.DisplayMember = "docType"
        ddlDocType.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader

        cmd.Connection.Close()


        'grdDragDoc.Rows(9)
        db = Nothing
        cmd = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub grdDragDoc_CellEditorInitialized(sender As Object, e As Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridViewCellEventArgs) Handles grdDragDoc.CellEditorInitialized

    Dim db As New gpcdb.dbaccess
    Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
    cmd = db.GetSqlDBCmd("gpc_DocumentType", CommandType.StoredProcedure)
    Dim ddlDocType As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn = New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn

    cmd.Connection.Open()

    ddlDocType.ValueMember = "gpcDocTypeID"
    ddlDocType.DisplayMember = "docType"
    ddlDocType.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader

    cmd.Connection.Close()

    If e.Column.Name = "ddlDocType" Then
        Dim editor As RadDropDownListEditor = TryCast(Me.grdDragDoc.ActiveEditor, RadDropDownListEditor)
        If Not editor Is Nothing Then
            CType((CType(Me.grdDragDoc.ActiveEditor, RadDropDownListEditor)).EditorElement, RadDropDownListEditorElement).RightToLeft = True
        End If
    End If

    'grdDragDoc.Columns.Add(ddlDocType)
    'grdDragDoc.Rows(9)
    db = Nothing
    cmd = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub grdDragDoc_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridViewCellEventArgs) Handles grdDragDoc.CellValueChanged
    Try
        Dim ddlDocType As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn = New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
        'If e.ColumnIndex = ddlDocType.Index Then
        Dim retreivedValue As Object = grdDragDoc.Rows(grdDragDoc.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(9)

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub DocumentListLoad()
    Try

        Dim objDoc As New gpcdb.document
        Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand

        cmd = objDoc.DocumentList(_ClientID)
        cmd.Connection.Open()
        grdDragDoc.LoadFrom(cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
        'lstDocuments.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)

        'Assign drop down list to column in the grid
        Dim ddlDocType As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn = New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn


        cmd.Connection.Close()
        cmd = Nothing
        objDoc = Nothing

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "DocumentListLoad", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can see how to setup combo box column in RadGridView: http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-columns-gridviewcomboboxcolumn.html

Answer (score 0):

```
GridViewComboBoxColumn supplierColumn = new GridViewComboBoxColumn();
supplierColumn.Name = "SupplierColumn";
supplierColumn.HeaderText = "Supplier";
supplierColumn.DataSource = this.suppliersBindingSource;
supplierColumn.ValueMember = "SupplierID";
supplierColumn.DisplayMember = "ContactName";
supplierColumn.FieldName = "SupplierID";
supplierColumn.Width = 200;
this.radGridView1.Columns.Add(supplierColumn);
```